# Swift | Аутентификация в приложении по sms

Tags: swift, token, sms, аутентификация

Изучаю сейчас, как делать приложение с авторизацией по sms. Есть представление как это можно сделать, но пока не понятно, как это всё можно соеденить.

**У меня есть метод для отправки sms с таким телом:**

```
{
    "phone":"+79994444444"
}
```

**И такой ответ:**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "message": "Successfully sended code!"
    },
    "error": null
}
```

**Далее идёт запрос на авторизацию с смс кодом с таким телом:**

```
{
    "phone":"+79994444444",
    "code":1234
}
```

**И такой ответ (при успехе):**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "access_token": "eeee...",
        "token_type": "Bearer",
        "expires_at": "2022-02-15 16:14:00"
    },
    "error": null
}
```

**Есть такие вопросы:**

1. Как и где сохранить токен пользователя при успешном логине? Нужно наверное модель сделать и распарсить ответ?
2. Как в дальнейшем использовать токен пользователя в запросах приложения?
3. Я так понимаю, открывать логин или главный скрин - можно добавить if-else в AppDelegate в application: didFinishLaunchWithOptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Я у себя сохраняю в папке приложения при помощи `NSUserDefaults`. Чтение:

   ```
   let preferences = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

   let currentLevelKey = "currentLevel"

   if preferences.objectForKey(currentLevelKey) == nil {
   //  Doesn't exist
   } else {
   let currentLevel = preferences.integerForKey(currentLevelKey)
   }
   ```

запись:

```
let preferences = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

let currentLevelKey = "currentLevel"

let currentLevel = ...
preferences.setInteger(currentLevel, forKey: currentLevelKey)


if !didSave {
    //  Couldn't save (I've never seen this happen in real world testing)
}
```

[вот есть статья](https://freakycoder.com/ios-notes-28-how-to-use-userdefaults-sharedpreferences-b52becd4f858) с использованием NSUserDefaults прям для хранения токенов

2. Использование = чтение из памяти (смотри выше)
3. Решение об открытии определенного экрана как вы правильно допустили можно реализовать через условный оператор. Сделайте проверку наличия ключа в памяти и если ключ в наличии то делайте переход дальше (смотри выше)

Comment: synchronize уже не нужен.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, немного устаревший вариант попался :( спасибо что заметили

Comment: @Andrew спасибо за помощь!